# Referencing json data in D3.js

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

Basically I'm doing a basic enough family tree where each person is represented by a  with their own properties. One property is "a Marriage" tag with can have attributes such as "married", "single" etc. but "widowed" is dependant on whether their spouse is dead or not. I decided to work off "id_number" as the marriage reference as different people can have the same name.

Assuming I have json data which looks like this:

```
var people = [
    { "name": "John Doe", "id_number": 1, "date_of_death": "1984", "married": 2, "father": 0, "mother": 0},
    { "name": "Jane Doe", "id_number": 2, "date_of_death": "1994", "married": 1, "father": 0, "mother": 0}
    ];

var person = d3.select("body").append("div")
    .data(people)
    .enter()
    .append("div")
    .text(function (d) { return d.name; })  
    .attr("id", function (d) { 
       if (typeof(d.married) != "undefined"){
         if (typeof(people[married].date_of_death) != "undefined"){ ## error occurs here
           m_status = "married";
         } else {
          m_status = "widowed";
         }
       }else{
         m_status = "single";
       }

       return m_status;
     });
```

My question is what is the proper syntax to reference a separate line of data in the same json file?

I have a feeling nodes solves the issue but I have yet to get any example node code working locally even without any changes...

Comment: Your JSON data denotes an array, so you would access the different "lines" as `people[0]`, `people[1]` etc.

Comment: That's what I thought thus the people[married] denotation but it isn't working out. I feel there is just something small going wrong

Comment: Wait figured it out in the shower! needed people[d.married] instead of people[married]. Knew it was something simple! also "widowed" and "married" should be swapped for any future person wondering